# ¿Cómo se le dice a un día con truenos?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Si hace mucho viento se puede decir un día [ventoso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bZGodnd). Si llueve se puede decir un día lluvioso. Ayer estaba tronando y no supe que adjetivo usar para describir el día. ¿Existe un adjetivo en español que describa un tiempo con bastantes truenos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te propongo algunas ideas:

> **[tronador, ra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=amXADuC)**
>
> 1. adj. Que truena.
>
> **[tronitoso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=anG55Vd)**
>
> 1. adj. coloq. Que hace ruido de truenos u otro semejante.
>
> **[tonante](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a0Kgntv)**
>
> 1. adj. Que truena. U. especialmente referido al dios Júpiter.

También puedes usar:

> **[borrascoso, sa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5vkb7tP)**
>
> 1. adj. Que causa borrascas. *Viento borrascoso.*
> 2. adj. Propenso a las borrascas. *El cabo de Hornos es borrascoso.*

Sobre todo dado que "borrasca" es una "perturbación atmosférica caracterizada por fuertes vientos, abundantes precipitaciones y, a veces, fenómenos eléctricos". Por tanto se podría decir que un día *borrascoso* incluye truenos. Ejemplo:

> *Pasó tronando el borrascoso día.*
>
> José María Heredia, "Poesías", 1810-1837 (Cuba).

También he encontrado:

> **[tronada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=amUOrNl)**
>
> 1. f. Tempestad de truenos.

Como en este ejemplo:

> *Aquel día será día de ira, día de calamidad y de miseria, día de tinieblas y escuridad, día de nieblas y tronada, día de trompeta y estruendo sobre las ciudades fuertes y sobre las altas esquinas.*
>
> Justo Cuervo, "Traducción del Compendio de Doctrina Cristiana", 1906 (España).

Comment: Genial, hay varias opciones entonces. Yo había pensado en la palabra "tronoso", pero creo que el DLE no coincide conmigo en pensar que es una buena idea =p

Answer (score 4):

Lo más parecido que se me ocurre es "tormentoso"

Comment: Yo también usaria tormentoso pero lo curioso es que la definición de tormenta del DLE no dice nada sobre truenos: *Perturbación atmosférica violenta acompañada de aparato eléctrico y viento fuerte, lluvia, nieve o granizo.* Otros diccionarios si añaden los truenos a la definición de tormenta.

Comment: @blonfu ¿"aparato eléctrico" no sería una referencia a los truenos?

Comment: @MauricioMartinez yo lo asociaba mas a los relámpagos pero supongo que si hay relámpagos hay truenos aunque no siempre se oigan. Puede que tengas razón